# Search form with multiple entry collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search

For a movie site that allows a user to search for a movie by entering actor names, I referenced the [Railscast on Advanced Search Forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form), but am having difficulty with searching multiple entries in the same parameter. (ie. multiple actor entries).

The code below allows for multiple actors to be selected, but I'm not sure how to rewrite the model code to allow for multiple actor_ids.

Feedback would be very much appreciated!

**searches/new.html.erb**

```
<%= f.label :actor_id %>
<%= f.collection_select :actor_id, Actor.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true}%>
```

**search.rb**

```
def movies
  @movies ||= find_movies
end

private
  def find_movies
    movies = movies.where(actor_id: actor_id)
  end
```

Comment: is your collection_select sending id's as values in your params?

Comment: Hi @KyleC. What do you mean by "as values"? If I select two actors (id=1 and id=2), then I see the following in my log: `Parameters: {"search"=>{"actor_id"=>["","1","2"]}, "commit"=>"Search", "id"=>"50"}`

Comment: are you saving these queries in your database?

Comment: currently, I'm only saving one actor id, as I only have a single actor_id column in my Search table. If I want to allow for up to three actors to be selected, do I need three actor_id columns in my Search table? If so, how should I name the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are saving these queries in your database try this

```
  def find_movies
     movies = Movie.order(:name)
     movies = movies.where(actor_id: actor_id) if actor_id.present?
  end
```

without saving the query you can implement this

In your search.rb

```
    def find_movies(actors)
       movies = Movie.where(:actor_id => actors)
    end
```

Then in your controller action where you are sending the parameters

```
  find_movies(params[:actor_id])
```

EDIT

to extract the ids from your actor_id use this

```
   ["actor_id", ["", "1", "2"]][1].delete_if {|f| f == ""}
```

so your method should look like this

```
  def find_movies
      ids = self.actor_id[1].delete_if {|f| f == ""}
      movies = Movie.order(:name)
      movies = movies.where(actor_id: ids) if actor_id.present?
  end
```

Comment: Thanks @Kyle. I actually had the same code as you suggested above, but had forgotten to include the first line that defines `movies`. However, I'm still unable to search with multiple actor_ids. This only works if I remove the `{:multple=>true}` option from the collection_select, and only allow a single actor_id to be entered. How can I apply this to work for multiple actor_ids?

Comment: The reason for that is you cannot save an array into your database, can you post the value of your actor_id column in your db and then we can parse and turn it into an array

Comment: Hi @Kyle. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by `value of your actor-id column in your db`. Currently, it is a single column of type integer, and for each search query, saves a single actor_id. Should I change this column to a string, so that it can save multiple actor_ids after they've been turned into a string?

Comment: Yes, I would make it a string and make them separated by a comma... I meant to post the value of the actor_id that you are saving. I wanted to know the format it was saving in (whether all the numbers were joined or separated)

Comment: I changed the actor_id column type to string, and now if I enter actor_1 and actor_2 through my browser, the logs show it is returning `["actor_id", ["", "1", "2"]]`. How can I parse this as you suggest?

Comment: Hi @Kyle, it turns out the actor_ids are not being saved correctly. Sorry, my logs are as described before, but through the console, when I look up a particular Search entry in which I selected designer_1 and designer_2, I find designer id to be `designer_id: "---\n- ''\n- '1'\n- '2'\n"`. How would I go about parsing this? Really appreciate your patient feedback.

Comment: "---\n- ''\n- '1'\n- '2'\n".scan(/\d+/)  , this will grab only the numbers out of the string